# How to Import an Excel data to SQL Table

Tags: mysql, excel

I want to import all my excel data to my web sql database. is that possible?

That is, 
  I'm trying to make a web site for school database and i have many school contact info as excel sheet. I need to import all that data to sql data base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the excel to a csv file and then use the mysqlimport statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:[image]